# Infix to Postfix with parentheses where 'operands' are not single tokens

Tags: c++, parsing, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I have to write a program that mimics the terminal bash shell where you can put commands together using connectors. An example input would be:

```
(echo "hello world" && ls -a) || (echo "hello world again" && ls -l)
```

This expression can be thought of as a infix expression, where:

A = echo "hello world"

B = ls -a

C = echo "hello world again"

D = ls -l

So the expression can be seen as:

```
(A && B) || (C && D)
```

The connectors && and || have no precendence.

Infix to postfix conversion has been covered extensively, but the 'operands' in this case are not single tokens like a number. They are a string.

I am having a hard time figuring out a good approach for parsing the command tokens so I can later treat them as one. I do not know if I have to scan each character individually in the line, or can split the input line by white space.

Does anyone have any ideas? I just do not want to start down a path of never ending case statements and figure out my method is not smart.

Comment: You need to come up with the (formal) production rules for the grammar you're trying to parse, and then write a lexer that follows those rules.  Advice to you is **not** to try and do this in an ad-hoc, [seat-of-your-pants](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seat-of-the-pants) type of coding -- you will regret it when you need to add some functionality and realize that you've written code that is so tightly wound, it needs to be redone from scratch.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how do I write formal production rules? Is there a link/resource you recommend for getting started?

Comment: [Try boost spirit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/introduction.html).

Comment: Something like `expr`, then expression is broken down as `expr : paren subexpr paren` and maybe a second rule `expr : expr connector expr`, and then you would define connector as `connector : && | ||` , etc.  Then when you have the grammar finished (extended BNF is the simplest to understand IMO), this is fed into something like boost spirit or lex/yacc to come up with the parser.

Answer (score 1):

Each item is still a single token. You just need to write a lexer that knows how to read a string as a single token. When a string is quoted, that's pretty easy. When it's not, it may be more difficult--you'll (probably) need to either decide on all the characters that can be in a string, or (equivalently) those that can't. Then when you start to read an un-quoted string, you continue until you encounter something that can't be part of the string.

Aside from lexing, conversion to postscript will be pretty much like it would be otherwise.